# Pythonic solution to display multi-dimensional tuple as a tree

Tags: python

I would like to show the tree-like structure contained in a multi-dimensional tuple by using the set of graphical glyphs that exist in Unicode fonts (e.g. \u2500, \u2502, \u2514 and others). Here is an example of the kind of output, I'm talking about:

```
>>> show_tree('(01, (02,  03, 04), 05, ((06, 07), 08), (09, (10, 11), (12, 13), 14), 15)')
┬─01
├─┬─02
│ ├─03
│ └─04
├─05
├─┬─┬─06
│ │ └─07
│ └─08
├─┬─09
│ ├─┬─10
│ │ └─11
│ ├─┬─12
│ │ └─13
│ └─14
└─15
```

Ideally, empty items, multi-words items, extra spaces around commas or parenthesis, as well as unbalanced parenthesis should be managed correctly, as in the following example:

```
>>> show_tree('( A, B multi-word item , (C,D), ( E  , ,  F ), G  )'))
┬─A
├─B multi-word item
├─┬─C
│ └─D
├─┬─E
│ ├─
│ └─F
└─G
```

I came up with a solution that works quite well (the examples above have been generated with it) but the implemented algorithm is not very elegant, and the code not very pythonic :

```
def show_tree(string):
    """display multidimensional tuple as a tree"""
    glyphs = ['\u252C\u2500','\u251C\u2500','\u2514\u2500','\u2502 ']
    tree, glyph, item = [], [], []
    for char in string:                                             # loop over chars in provided string
        if char in ',)' and item:                                   # add glyph prefix and current item to tree
            tree.append(glyph + [''.join(item).strip()]); item = []
        if char == ',':                                             # update glyph prefix for new item in sublist
            glyph = [glyphs[3]] * (len(glyph)-1) + [glyphs[1]]
        elif char == ')':                                           # update glyph prefix for last item in sublist
            tree[-1][-2] = glyphs[2]; glyph = glyph[:-1] 
        elif char == '(':                                           # update glyph prefix for first item in sublist
            glyph.append(glyphs[0])
        else:                                                       # other chars are simply added to current item
            item.append(char)
    return '\n'.join(''.join(node) for node in tree)
```

So I would like to get some ideas for an improved implementation, maybe using regular expressions or other advanced parsing techniques. Thank you very much for any hint...

Comment: You might get a better response at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KyleL: Good advice ! I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @KyleL, I posted my question to codereview.stackexchange.com, and got a very elegant solution  by @Peilonrayz. The complete answer is available [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238043/pythonic-solution-to-display-multi-dimensional-tuple-as-a-tree), but if someone is interested, I just paste his code below:

```
def show_tree(root):
    return '\n'.join(build_tree(root))

def build_tree(node):
    if not isinstance(node, tuple):
        yield str(node)
        return

    values = [build_tree(n) for n in node]
    if len(values) == 1:
        yield from build_lines('──', '  ', values[0])
        return

    start, *mid, end = values
    yield from build_lines('┬─', '│ ', start)
    for value in mid:
        yield from build_lines('├─', '│ ', value)
    yield from build_lines('└─', '  ', end)

def build_lines(first, other, values):
    yield first + next(values)
    for value in values:
        yield other + value
```

combined with some execution samples:

```
>>> print(show_tree(('01', ('02',  '03', '04'), '05', (('06', '07'), '08'), ('09', ('10', '11'), ('12', '13'), '14'), '15')))
┬─01
├─┬─02
│ ├─03
│ └─04
├─05
├─┬─┬─06
│ │ └─07
│ └─08
├─┬─09
│ ├─┬─10
│ │ └─11
│ ├─┬─12
│ │ └─13
│ └─14
└─15
>>> print(show_tree(('A', 'B multi-word item', ('C', 'D'), ('E', '', 'F'), 'G')))
┬─A
├─B multi-word item
├─┬─C
│ └─D
├─┬─E
│ ├─
│ └─F
└─G
>>> print(show_tree((1, ((2,),), (3, 4, (5,)))))
┬─1
├─────2
└─┬─3
  ├─4
  └───5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [tree-format](https://github.com/jml/tree-format) which is doing what you are trying to achieve.